# psql: FATAL: could not write init file

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

as the title points out, I'm getting this error when trying to connect to a PostgreSql database from command line, using PostgreSQL.

The client machine is an Ubuntu 11.10 x86_64 and the PostgreSQL libraries are from Version 9.1

Server is PostgreSql 8.3.

This is the command that I executed:

```
psql -U postgres -d my_database -h 192.168.0.161 -p 5432 -c "select * from xxyy"
```

I get the same results when I use `sudo` or `su postgres`.

The sad thing is that I can connect without problems using `pgAdmin`.

Any hint?

Comment: Can you connect from other machines? Also, try to use a client with the same version as the server 8.3.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue earlier.

Upon checking the log, I saw that postgres was complaining about diskspace. A `df -h` showed that the device had 0MB free space available. After freeing up some space, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-[your_version]-main.log` on the server for signs of what's failing.

You might also try to launch that `psql` command locally, from the server, to see whether the problem is really with your client.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. In my case it was a full file system. You may have other file system problems...

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://serverfault.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.